# Memory issues when upgrading from 2.2.6 to 2.3

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.6, memory

I am trying to upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.3, but the updater doens't even start. I get this message in the log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php on line 272
```

I havem 1024M of allocated memory. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

magento 2.3 requirement of 2 gb ram 
[image]

Comment: please accept if it is helpful

Comment: Increased the memory to 2G, got the same error.